# Simplest way to call a script in "path_to_python_environment/Scripts"?

Tags: python

What's the best way to call from within a python script another script located in `path_to_python_environment/Scripts`, e.g. `path_to_python_environment/Scripts/gdal_calc.py`?

**Non working solutions**:

1)

```
import gdal_calc
gdal_calc('--help')
```

2)

```
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen('python gdal_calc.py --help')
```

**Working solution**, but there must be a simpler way:

```
import subprocess
path_to_python_environment = os.path.dirname(sys.executable)
path_to_script = os.path.join(path_to_python_environment, 'Scripts', 'gdal_calc.py')
subprocess.Popen('python ' + path_to_script + ' --help')
```

Comment: `import myEnv.Scripts.gdal_calc`? but import and subprocess do different thing.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a shell script, you can always launch it from a python script with something like this:

```
# import section
import os

# Manual input
a_source = "aaa.tif"
b_source = "bbb.tif"
output = "out.tif"
calc = '"(A**B)*(B==1)"'

# The command itself
gdal_calc = 'python {Path root}/Lib/site-packages/osgeo/scripts/gdal_calc.py ' \
            '-A {0} ' \
            '-B {1} ' \
            '--outfile={2} ' \
            '--calc={3} ' \
            '--type=Float32 ' \
            '--overwrite'.format(a_source, b_source, output, calc)

# Launch the command
os.system(gdal_calc)
```

I found this much easier and clearer.